# Port a pygtk based C API to pygobject

Tags: python, c, gtk, pygtk, pygobject

As recommended by pygtk itself, the way forward is GObjectIntrospection. I would like to port a C API for python which uses pygtk.h and pygobject.h. Can anyone show me the way towards documentation on how to do this ?

Comment: `pygobject.h` is still needed, only PyGTK is no longer necessary. The question is: what does the C API do? If it merely exposes custom GTK widgets to Python, you shouldn't be neededing it at all, they should already be available through gobject-introspection.

Comment: Actually, https://github.com/codebrainz/geanypy is the codebase I am talking about. It exposes geany editor plugin API for python but uses pygtk.

Comment: It's not obvious why it needs `pygtk.h` - searching doesn't reveal any `pygtk_` function or type being called, except for `init_pygtk()`. A good start would be to simply remove the include and see what breaks, and if the required functionality can be implemented using only PyGObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `pygtk_init()` and `pygobject_init()` are macros found in pygtk headers. We should use `init_pygobject()` function which takes 3 arguments major, minor and micro which are version numbers or (-1, -1, -1) which is kinda default should work. Also inorder to smoothly run your ported app you may require `PySys_SetArgv(0, "[]")` which was in my case.

Here is the code I was trying this for:

https://github.com/sagarchalise/geanypy/tree/gtk3